# Child process and a mutex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, fork, mutex

I'm creating a script that plays music using `mplayer`. The way I'm trying to make it work is to allow multiple threads (via HTTP requests) can play a song. However, I don't want multiple songs playing at once, and I don't want a queue. I just want to play the most recent request. I'm having issues, though, with my mutex. It doesn't always return locked when I expect it to.

```
Class Handler

    def initialize
        @read_io, @write_io = IO.pipe
        @child = nil
        @mutex = Mutex.new
    end

    def play_song_with_id(id)
        if @mutex.locked? then # this doesn't always return as expected
            stop_mplayer # this is how I interupt the child
            @mutex.unlock
        end
        if @mutex.lock then
            @child = fork do
                STDIN.reopen(@read_io)
                `mplayer -really-quiet "#{id}"`
                exit
            end
            Process.detatch(@child)
        end
    end

    def stop_mplayer() 
        @write_io.write "q" # mplayer takes input 'q' to quit
    end

end
```

And just to give the full picture, here's how I'm routing the requests. A simple WEBrick server:

```
if $0 == __FILE__ then

    # Create the server
    server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port=>port)
    ip = IPSocket.getaddress(Socket.gethostname)

    # Create a handler
    handler = Handler.new

    # Define routes
    server.mount "/handle", Routes::HandleRoute, handler

    # Handle interuptions
    trap "INT" do
        server.shutdown
    end

    # Start the server
    puts "\n===================="
    puts " * Server running at #{ip} on port #{port}"
    puts "====================\n\n"

    server.start
end
```

And the route:

```
class HandleRoute < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet

    def initialize server, handler
        @handler = handler
    end

    def do_POST(request, response)
        if(request.body)
            @handler.play_song_with_id(request.body)
        end
    end

end
```

TL;DR - Somehow, sometimes two songs will play at once, and I'd like to use `@mutex` to prevent that. I want to play the most recent request, and stop any playback that is currently happening. I'm wondering the way I'm trying to stop playback is the problem, and not the mutex? If so, what would be a better way to interrupt the child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try simplifying your usage of the mutex. Your current implementation looks vulnerable to timing problems between the time the mutex is unlocked and locked again.

```
class Handler
  def play_song_with_id(id)
    @mutex.synchronize do
        stop_mplayer
        @child = fork do
            STDIN.reopen(@read_io)
            `mplayer -really-quiet "#{id}"`
            exit
        end
        Process.detach(@child)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This simplified method seems to have done the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really needs a mutex in this case. Since you want to play only the most recent, you can always kill the mplayer whenever a new request is done. So:

```
def play_song_with_id(id)
  stop_mplayer_if_any
  start_mplayer
end


def stop_mplayer_if_any() 
  @write_io.write "q"
rescue => e # Please do a better job here, rescuing only the really expected exceptions
  logger.info "Rescuing from #{e.inspect} and ignoring"
end

def start_mplayer
  @child = fork do
    STDIN.reopen(@read_io)
    `mplayer -really-quiet "#{id}"`
    exit
  end
end
```

And no sync problems when there is no need for it.